# Android Application Development for Dummies - Examples Wont Run

Tags: java, android

I brought *Android Application Development for Dummies* a year or two ago, and I have finally sat down to try this stuff out. I studied Software Engineering ~ 5 years ago, so I have some idea, but Eclipse has me beat.

I set up the Development Environment as stated in the book (a few variations for newer versions etc) and set up my first app, aptly named 'Hello Android'. As soon as I finish the wizard I get errors.

I get `R cannot be resolved to a variable`, and after googling, I found loads of helpful info here. But none which seems to fix my problem. I have `R.Java` in the `gen` folder. When I attempt `Project > Clean` I get

> Error executing aidl. Please check aidl is present at C:\android\adt-bundle-windows-x86-20130219\sdkplatform-tools\aidl.exe

I checked the directory and `\sdkplatform-tools\` doesn't exist. Instead the folder structure is `\sdk\platform-tools\`. I thought I'd attempt to fix this, so I copied the contents of `\platform-tools\` to the directry specified in the error message, but no luck.

Also, I tried some of the examples that come with the SDK, and I get the same error.

So, I'm thinking that something is fundamentally wrong with my set up, I just don't know what.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you correctly install Android SDK? If you want to check it, in Eclipse Window->Preferences->Android if there is red X icon you are missing sdk.

Answer (score 0):

Got to Window -> Preferences -> Android and make sure your SDK location is set correctly.